# Frequency of characters in C - weird numbers

Tags: c

Here is my function:

```
void printStatistics(const char *current) {
    int count = 0, i = 0, length = strlen(current);
    int lowercaseLetters[26] = {0};
    int uppercaseLetters[26] = {0};
    char *token;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (current[i] >= 'a' & current[i] <= 'z') {
            lowercaseLetters[current[i] - 'a']++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (current[i] >= 'A' & current[i] <= 'Z') {
            uppercaseLetters[current[i] - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    char tempToken[10] = "";
    strcpy(tempToken, current);
    token = strtok(tempToken, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        count++;
    }

    printf("Statistics:\n"
           "\tlength:\t\t%d\n"
           "\tword:\t\t%d\n"
           "Frequency:\n", length, count);

    printf("Printing Uppercase matrix...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("\tfrequency of %c:\t%d\n", 'a' + i, uppercaseLetters[i]);
    }

    printf("Printing Lowercase matrix...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("\tfrequency of %c:\t%d\n", 'a' + i, lowercaseLetters[i]);
    }
}
```

and here is what I get when I try to check string `gggggggggggggggggggg BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`

```
Statistics:
    length:         74
    word:           2
Frequency:
Printing Uppercase matrix...
    frequency of a: 1734829927
    frequency of b: 1734829927
    frequency of c: 1107322727
    frequency of d: 1111638594
    frequency of e: 1111638594
    frequency of f: 1111638594
    frequency of g: 1111638594
    frequency of h: 1111638594
    frequency of i: 1111638594
    frequency of j: 1111638594
    frequency of k: 1111638594
    frequency of l: 1111638594
    frequency of m: 1111638594
    frequency of n: 1111638594
    frequency of o: 1111638594
    frequency of p: 1111638594
    frequency of q: 0
    frequency of r: 0
    frequency of s: 0
    frequency of t: 0
    frequency of u: 0
    frequency of v: 0
    frequency of w: 0
    frequency of x: 0
    frequency of y: 0
    frequency of z: 0
Printing Lowercase matrix...
    frequency of a: 0
    frequency of b: 0
    frequency of c: 0
    frequency of d: 0
    frequency of e: 0
    frequency of f: 0
    frequency of g: 20
    frequency of h: 0
    frequency of i: 0
    frequency of j: 0
    frequency of k: 0
    frequency of l: 0
    frequency of m: 0
    frequency of n: 0
    frequency of o: 0
    frequency of p: 0
    frequency of q: 0
    frequency of r: 0
    frequency of s: 0
    frequency of t: 0
    frequency of u: 0
    frequency of v: 0
    frequency of w: 0
    frequency of x: 0
    frequency of y: 0
    frequency of z: 0
```

Why am I getting these weird long numbers in the uppercase matrix?  It seems like I'm not indexing outside of the uppercase array - I'm handling it in the exact same way as the lowercase array.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Those `&`s should be `&&`s. Idk if that's your problem, but that will probably bite you at some point.

Comment: Initial observation is that logical operator like && should be used instead of  bitwise operator &

Comment: `char tempToken[10] = ""; strcpy(tempToken, current);` The input string is much longer than 9 characters (plus terminating NUL) so that `strcpy` will cause memory corruption.

Comment: Also, there is corruption as current is greater than tempToken while performing strcpy.

Comment: Ok, I understand using the logical operator and trying to copy in a string too large for that array.  Could corruption due to the tempChar array being too small really cause the later parts of the code to error?

Comment: As @kaylum points out, you are writing past the end of your buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour. In this case, you are copying parts of your string into the memory locations occupied by `uppercaseLetters` **Note:* `1734829927` is `67676767` in hex (="gggg"), and `1111638594` is `42424242` (="BBB").

Comment: @user2836976 memory corruption can cause all sorts of unpredictable behaviour. In C there is even a term for that - Undefined Behaviour. So, absolutely yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing **[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** by writing past the end of a buffer. The main problem is here:

```
char tempToken[10] = "";
strcpy(tempToken, current);
```

Since you don't check the length of the string at `current` before copying it to `tempToken`, you are liable to go past the 9-character limit (allowing one extra character for the terminating `'\0'` byte) and corrupt the memory allocated to other data.

In your case, this is what the stack looks like when the program calls `printStatistics()`: (but see note below)

```
+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------
| char tempToken[10] | int uppercaseLetters[26] | int lowercaseLetters[26] | token, etc...
+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------
```

When you copy the string `gggggggggggggggggggg BBBBBBBBBBBBBB...` to `tempToken`, the first ten characters fill this array completely, and the remainder are written into the array `uppercaseLetters` instead. So when you fetch your data from this array, you are actually reading back these ASCII characters (1734829927 == 0x67676767  == "gggg"; 1111638594 == 0x42424242 == "BBBB").

If you copy a longer string, you will also overwrite `lowercaseLetters`, followed by the other variables (`token`, etc.).

The [`strncpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) function is designed to avoid this sort of problem. You should use it too.

---

Also, as others have pointed out, you are using a bitwise "and" operator `&` where a logical "and" `&&` is required.

---

> - **Note:** Other systems and other compilers will store things differently, and will misbehave in other ways. Your code simply crashed when compiled on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

The big issues have already been properly covered, but there are a couple of extra observations, too long for comment. First, try to avoid using *magic numbers* in your code. If you need a constant for `26`, `#define` one or use an `enum`, e.g.

```
#define ABET 26
```

or

```
enum { ABET = 26 };
```

Then you can use the constant throughout your code (and you only have to change it in a single location if you need to adjust it later). Then you can do something similar to the following (note: I dislike typing, so your `lowercaseletters` has simply been replace with `lc` below, etc...

```
int count = 0, i = 0, len = (int)strlen (s),
    lc[ABET] = { 0 },
    uc[ABET] = { 0 };
...
for (i = 0; i < ABET; i++)
```

Next, there is no need for two separate loops to fill the upper/lower frequency arrays, e.g. (and replacing `current` with `s`)

```
/* no need for 2 separate loops */
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if ('a' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'z')
        lc[s[i] - 'a']++;
    if ('A' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'Z')
        uc[s[i] - 'A']++;
}
```

(*note:* writing your comparison as `if ('a' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'z')` may make the values within each set a bit more apparent, that's just a matter of taste, either way is correct)

You may also find declaring a set of `delimiters` in a variable (say `delim`) provides a convenient way to prevent hardcoding the delimiters within each of your `strtok` calls adding to maintainability, e.g.

```
char *delim = " \t,;\"'";
```

There is nothing wrong with your use of `while` with `strtok`, but since you are only interested in `token` within loop scope, using a `for` loop and `c99` loop declaration results in a slightly more compact expression, e.g.

```
for (char *tok = strtok (tmp, delim); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, delim))
    count++;
```

In `printStatistics`, (`prnstats` below) what happens if your `current` (my `s`) is `NULL` or *empty*? Since you cannot classify the frequency of either, a simple check at the beginning of your function can prevent undefined behavior.

```
if (!s || !*s) return;
```

You can include an error message if you like, e.g.

```
if (!s || !*s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "prnstats() error: invalid parameter.\n");
    return;
}
```

Putting all of that together, along with the traditional elimination of the `MixedCase` or `camelCase` variables in C, and eliminated a bit more typing, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ABET 26

void prnstats (const char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] :
                "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
                "A QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.";

    prnstats (s);

    return 0;
}

void prnstats (const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;

    int count = 0, i = 0, len = (int)strlen (s),
        lc[ABET] = { 0 },
        uc[ABET] = { 0 };
    char *delim = " \t,;\"'";

    /* no need for 2 separate loops */
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ('a' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'z')
            lc[s[i] - 'a']++;
        if ('A' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'Z')
            uc[s[i] - 'A']++;
    }

    char tmp[len + 1];    /* a vla is fine here */
    strcpy (tmp, s);
    for (char *tok = strtok (tmp, delim); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, delim))
        count++;

    printf ("Statistics:\n"
            "  length :  %3d\n" 
            "  words  :  %3d\n\n", len, count);

    /* no need for 2 separate loops for dual-columns */
    printf ("Frequency:\n  Uppercase    Lowercase\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ABET; i++)
        printf ("    %c : %2d       %c : %2d\n",
                'A' + i, uc[i], 'a' + i, lc[i]);

}
```

Look things over, think about why words is `17` below, and let me know if you have any questions.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/wordfreq
Statistics:
  length :   84
  words  :   17

Frequency:
  Uppercase    Lowercase

    A :  2       a :  2
    B :  1       b :  1
    C :  1       c :  1
    D :  1       d :  1
    E :  2       e :  2
    F :  1       f :  1
    G :  1       g :  1
    H :  1       h :  1
    I :  1       i :  1
    J :  1       j :  1
    K :  1       k :  1
    L :  1       l :  1
    M :  1       m :  1
    N :  1       n :  1
    O :  4       o :  4
    P :  1       p :  1
    Q :  1       q :  1
    R :  2       r :  2
    S :  1       s :  1
    T :  1       t :  1
    U :  2       u :  2
    V :  1       v :  1
    W :  1       w :  1
    X :  1       x :  1
    Y :  1       y :  1
    Z :  1       z :  1
```

Comment: Well this is a weird questions to have that test case, but yes, we would need to sort further if there were going to be multiple occurrences of the same letter. Instead of just testing the first letter, I would have to write in a comparison until they are no longer the same. I'll update with another version to handle the same first char, but it will have to be in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

your call to strcpy:

strcpy(tempToken, current);

Is writing past the end of the buffer. This is producing undefined behavior, and in this case, effectively destroying the data you've collected in your 2 arrays.
consider using [strnlen_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to find the length of the buffer of which you are trying to make a temporary copy. and [strcpy_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to ensure you do not overwrite the buffer.

Additionally, at first glance, the usage of '&' made me tilt my head. If this was not intentional, be very careful. It works here because the >= and <= operators produce a boolean value, but in general is not the best idea for trying to find if two values are "true".